# Get the most accurate position with flutter geolocator package

Tags: flutter, dart, gps, geolocator

In flutter I managed to get the current position using the geolocator package. At the moment i can press on a button and then the location is fetched one time. I requested it with a high accuracy. But I noticed also that on every time i hit the button, the position is very bumpy. I know this is normal since on maps etc it's also behaving like this. Also the accuracy is jumping back and forth.

But in my app it's very important to get the current position as accurate as possible.its not needed to track the whole time, but when I hit the button I want the most accurate position that is possible.

What's the approach in geolocator to realise this?

I could think of triggering the location finding logic automatically every 2 seconds for example 1 minute long and just save the measurement with the highest accuracy. But is this way to go usually? Any other approaches/libraries?

Thanks a lot.